# ASP.NET Previous Page Retain Search

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, postback

I know this has been asked of other languages and through the use of Javascript however I have a similar question.

In .NET is there any way in which I can post to another page and then when I press a 'Back' Button on the page after editing or whatever it takes me back to the First Page.

The catch is the first page also has a datatable that may be paged at the time.  How do I retain this original data and its page and how to I redirect back to this.

If its not worth implementing or will make a mess to maintain then I can ignore it but I feel I should ask far better programmers before I make this decision.

An Example

[Page 1] -> Enter Search Text -> Get Result -> Page to Page (x) -> Click URL on Row
[Page 2] -> Loads data from previous url -> Clicks Button Save -> Clicks Button Back

Desired Result: Takes me to exactly where I left off page 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save data into `Session` before leaving the current page and when you back to this page read the Session key and if it is found/available (not null) then assign `Session` data to control properties.

Comment: Not overly keen in sessions considering they work across browser windows meaning one session will be mangled against another.  Basicly imagine me running two seperate queries in Google and pressing back in two different tabs.  I am looking for that type of functionality except keeping it code driven.  I could use Javascript:Back(-1) but thats very hacky.

Comment: I've answered ( and confused) because from this *text ->*  - *...when I press a 'Back' Button on the **page** after editing...*. I'm with  `JavaScript.back`.